# Google Forms - Change date format for all respondents

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-forms

In Google Forms the date format is changed according to Language settings in Google account of the respondent.
I want the date format to be the same for all respondents.

Can I put some code in Apps script?
I tried the following to prefill the date:

```
function doGet(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('1esX110YGnCOK8SJcz3jrll9ZiZZAhiIlpHxCTYbGcMg');
  var questions = form.getItems();
  var question2=questions[0];
  var time=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd-MM-yyyy");
  var prefilledTime=form.createResponse().withItemResponse(question2.asTextItem().createResponse(time));  
  var URL=prefilledTime.toPrefilledUrl();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>window.top.location.href=\"" + URL + "\";</script>");
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the case of Google Form, when the Google Form is submitted, you can see the submitted date to the column "A" of the Spreadsheet including the response values. This value is automatically added. In that case, the value of column "A" is the date object. From your showing script, it seems that you are using `new Date()`. From your script, I thought that the value of column "A" might be able to be used. How about this? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I don't want to change the date format in the response sheet, but in the Form itself. I have a question where I ask the respondent to input a date, but the date format is different based on the Google account settings. I don't want my respondents to be confused about mm/dd or dd/mm on the moment they are filling in the form.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that you wanted to make users input the date as the date question in Google Form. If my understanding is correct, in this case, I think that the retrieved values are the date object. By this, even when the date is submitted from the various accounts, the values can be used as the date object. How about this? But, if my understanding was not correct, I apologize.